# Get specific information from text file

Tags: java, file, text

I have a text file and it has ten lines in it which all contain this exact information "25987 20.7". So my question is, how can I only take the second number (20.7) and discard the first one?

Comment: Search about java BufferedReader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the split function of a string.

Therefore you read in the complete line into a string variable, e.g. `line`, and then use `line.split(" ")` with a space as argument.

This will return an array containing both values, of which you can proceed with the second.
For further information: [Java String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

You asked about the [farmer, corn, goose and fox problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox,_goose_and_bag_of_beans_puzzle), and deleted your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33702822/state-space-representation-of-farmer-corn-goose-and-fox) after it was well answered, something that is not quite fair to do for others with a similar problem or for the effort put in by the answerer, or for your instructors if they wish to see if you have used any borrowed code.  For all their benefits, let me post Daniel Mclam's deleted answer for the benefit of others:

---

Normally I would not provide a solution to a poorly worded question as this but I have found it to be an interesting problem if I have understood it correctly. Please make sure to also provide some source code next time so we can see what you have tried.(Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, for how to ask a good question)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //scanner object for user input
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

    //define objects
    //Use true and false to determine the side
    boolean farmer=false;
    boolean fox=false;
    boolean goose=false;
    boolean corn=false;

    //Show rules
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Farmer, Goose, Fox, Corn Problem.");
    System.out.println("The Fox and Goose cannot be left alone.");
    System.out.println("The Goose and Corn cannot be left alone.");
    System.out.println("You may only bring one object across the river at a time.");

    //loop flag
    boolean isFinished=false;

    while(!isFinished)
    {
        //show objects on the same side as the farmer
        System.out.println("\nThe objects on your side of the river are:");
        if(farmer==fox)
        {
            System.out.println("1.Fox ");
        }
        if(farmer==goose)
        {
            System.out.println("2.Goose ");
        }
        if(farmer==corn)
        {
            System.out.println("3.Corn ");
        }

        System.out.println("4.Nothing ");

        //get user selection and validate
        //just makes sure that the object is on the same side as the farmer
        //if true move the object then test if valid after switch

        boolean isValidInput=false;
        int userSelection;
        do
        {
            System.out.print("\nEnter the number for the object you wish to move:");
            userSelection=input.nextInt();
            if(userSelection==1)
            {
                if(fox==farmer)
                {
                    farmer=!farmer;
                    fox=!fox;
                    isValidInput=true;
                }
            }
            else if(userSelection==2)
            {
                if(goose==farmer)
                {
                    farmer=!farmer;
                    goose=!goose;
                    isValidInput=true;
                }
            }
            else if(userSelection==3)
            {
                if(corn==farmer)
                {
                    farmer=!farmer;
                    corn=!corn;
                    isValidInput=true;
                }
            }
            else if(userSelection==4)
            {
                    farmer=!farmer;
                    isValidInput=true;
            }
            else
            {
                isValidInput=false;
            }
        }while(!isValidInput);


        //check solution 
        boolean isValid=false;

        if((fox==goose && farmer!=fox))
        {
            System.out.println("\nFox and goose cannot stay together.");
        }
        else if(goose==corn && farmer!=goose)
        {
            System.out.println("\nGoose and corn cannot stay together.");
        }
        else
        {
            isValid=true;
        }


        //if the solution is not valid switch objects back and request user input again
        if(!isValid)
        {
            if(userSelection==1)
            {
                if(fox==farmer)
                {
                    farmer=!farmer;
                    fox=!fox;
                    isValidInput=true;
                }
            }
            else if(userSelection==2)
            {
                if(goose==farmer)
                {
                    farmer=!farmer;
                    goose=!goose;
                    isValidInput=true;
                }
            }
            else if(userSelection==3)
            {
                if(corn==farmer)
                {
                    farmer=!farmer;
                    corn=!corn;
                    isValidInput=true;
                }
            }
            else if(userSelection==4)
            {
                    farmer=!farmer;
                    isValidInput=true;
            }
            else
            {
                isValidInput=false;
            }
        }

        //check if final solution achieved
        if(fox && goose && corn && farmer)
        {
            System.out.println("\nYou Win, Good Job!!!");
            isFinished=true;
        }

    }//end while

}   //end main
```