# State Space Representation of Farmer, Corn, Goose and Fox

Tags: java

I have to write a program that solves the farmer, corn, goose and fox problem. Though I know how to solve the problem in my mind and I know the rules of the probelm (like the goose cannot stay with the fox or it will be eaten) I am confused on how to represent the rules in code.

Comment: When asking your question, start out by assuming that folks reading it have no clue as to the problem that you're trying to solve and the specific problem with your code, and then ask your question in such a way that our ignorance gets fully solved. Your current question is unfortunately almost impossible for most of us to parse or understand. Please try to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I have found it to be an interesting problem if I have understood it correctly.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //scanner object for user input
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    
    //define objects
    //Use true and false to determine the side
    boolean farmer=false;
    boolean fox=false;
    boolean goose=false;
    boolean corn=false;
    
    //Show rules
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Farmer, Goose, Fox, Corn Problem.");
    System.out.println("The Fox and Goose cannot be left alone.");
    System.out.println("The Goose and Corn cannot be left alone.");
    System.out.println("You may only bring one object across the river at a time.");
    
    //loop flag
    boolean isFinished=false;
    
    while(!isFinished)
    {
        //show objects on the same side as the farmer
        System.out.println("\nThe objects on your side of the river are:");
        if(farmer==fox)
        {
            System.out.println("1.Fox ");
        }
        if(farmer==goose)
        {
            System.out.println("2.Goose ");
        }
        if(farmer==corn)
        {
            System.out.println("3.Corn ");
        }
        
        System.out.println("4.Nothing ");
        
        //get user selection and validate
        //just makes sure that the object is on the same side as the farmer
        //if true move the object then test if valid after switch
        
        boolean isValidInput=false;
        int userSelection;
        do
        {
            System.out.print("\nEnter the number for the object you wish to move:");
            userSelection=input.nextInt();
            if(userSelection==1)
            {
                if(fox==farmer)
                {
                    farmer=!farmer;
                    fox=!fox;
                    isValidInput=true;
                }
            }
            else if(userSelection==2)
            {
                if(goose==farmer)
                {
                    farmer=!farmer;
                    goose=!goose;
                    isValidInput=true;
                }
            }
            else if(userSelection==3)
            {
                if(corn==farmer)
                {
                    farmer=!farmer;
                    corn=!corn;
                    isValidInput=true;
                }
            }
            else if(userSelection==4)
            {
                    farmer=!farmer;
                    isValidInput=true;
            }
            else
            {
                isValidInput=false;
            }
        }while(!isValidInput);
                    

        //check solution 
        boolean isValid=false;
        
        if((fox==goose && farmer!=fox))
        {
            System.out.println("\nFox and goose cannot stay together.");
        }
        else if(goose==corn && farmer!=goose)
        {
            System.out.println("\nGoose and corn cannot stay together.");
        }
        else
        {
            isValid=true;
        }
        
        
        //if the solution is not valid switch objects back and request user input again
        if(!isValid)
        {
            if(userSelection==1)
            {
                if(fox==farmer)
                {
                    farmer=!farmer;
                    fox=!fox;
                    isValidInput=true;
                }
            }
            else if(userSelection==2)
            {
                if(goose==farmer)
                {
                    farmer=!farmer;
                    goose=!goose;
                    isValidInput=true;
                }
            }
            else if(userSelection==3)
            {
                if(corn==farmer)
                {
                    farmer=!farmer;
                    corn=!corn;
                    isValidInput=true;
                }
            }
            else if(userSelection==4)
            {
                    farmer=!farmer;
                    isValidInput=true;
            }
            else
            {
                isValidInput=false;
            }
        }
        
        //check if final solution achieved
        if(fox && goose && corn && farmer)
        {
            System.out.println("\nYou Win, Good Job!!!");
            isFinished=true;
        }
        
    }//end while
    
}   //end main
```

Comment: I had to flag the moderators and request that this question be reopened after it had be closed by the original poster. I felt that it was not fair that your good answer should be deleted with this (poor) question.

Comment: Thanks, I hope many users will find this answer as helpful as I found it fun to solve.